# Is there a way to reverse the effect of a chown -R xxx:xxx /* command in debian?

Tags: debian, reverse, undo, chown

This an unfortunate situation where I had copied a string starting with the characters /* and I was trying to change the ownership of a directory on my debian machine.  Unfortunately as I reached for the mouse I right clicked and executed the command `chown -R xxx:xxx /*`.

Is there any way to reverse this from some sort of log?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install time-machine` -- seriously, once you overwrite something there is no record of it.  Hence backups, version control, ...

Comment: I just thought that since all the files are still there, with just the ownership changed, there could be a record of the changes made and I could maybe write a script to reverse the changes.  It would be awesome if this were so.

Comment: Not by default. If you have installed something like `aide`, it keeps a database including the owner. Or for files which are part of debian packages, `apt` has a database.